# Как перевести веб-форму в drupal7?

Tags: drupal

всем привет!
делаю сайт мультиязычный(русский,англи-й)
вопрос,как сделать мультиязычными слова в inputах
как здесь http://flybike.info/ru/tours/(к примеру-ваше имя,ваш email)?

function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $language;
    $ln = $language->language;

if($form_id == 'rent_now_entityform_edit_form'){

```
  if(isset($_GET['nid'])){
      if($_GET['nid'] == 22){$form['field_rent_now_equipment'][$ln]['#default_value'] = "Motorcycle Honda GoldWing 1800";}
      if($_GET['nid'] == 23){$form['field_rent_now_equipment'][$ln]['#default_value'] = "Tricycle Honda GoldWing 1800";}
  };

  $form['#theme'] = 'custom_form_rent_now_function';
```

//      $output = '';
//      $output .=  '<div class="description"><span>*</span> Поля, отмеченные этим знаком, обязательны для заполнения</div>';
//      $form['submitted']['training'] = array(
//          '#markup' => $output,
//          '#weight' => 100,
//      );
//      dm($form);

}
    if($form_id == 'reserve_entityform_edit_form'){
      if(isset($_GET['nid'])){
          if($_GET['nid'] == 126){$form['field_tours']['und']['#default_value'] = "Day Tour";}
          if($_GET['nid'] == 127){$form['field_tours']['und']['#default_value'] = "Night Tour";}
          if($_GET['nid'] == 128){$form['field_tours']['und']['#default_value'] = "Custom Tour";}
      };
      $form['#theme'] = 'custom_form_theme_function';
      //$form['field_rent_now_your_name']['und'][0]['value']['#description'] = "";
      //$form['field_rent_now_your_name']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = "Ваше имя*";
  };
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот функционал есть в Drupal по умолчанию. При переключении языка сайта в автомате будут подхватываться нужные переводы. Если форма кастомная, то нужно использовать функцию [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) для всего текста который будет на нескольких языках.

Comment: да.Форма кастомная
куда этот код вставлять?в custom модуль?

Comment: Вероятно в модуль в котором эта форма объявлена. 

'title' => t('Title form');

Теперь в переводах языков будет возможность перевести этот текст на различные языки.

Comment: я добавил кусок кода где выводится форма,можете сказать куда его именно вставить?

Comment: о_0 Начните с изучения form_api.. 
Я уже привёл ссылку на документацию по использованию этой функции, там есть даже примеры, читайте внимательно.
Ещё пример: 
$form['field_rent_now_your_name']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Ваше имя'); 
Теперь в переводах(admin/config/regional/translate/translate) появится эта фраза и её можно будет перевести на различные языки.